# Formula in python for sum function when inserting line in openoffice calc

Tags: python, openoffice.org

Use ods to make calc report

No problem with the creation of the report, but the sum in the result is static.
Now I try to use the sum() calc function to make the sum of lines created with python loop, and so to have dynamic sum.

I try to put the sum() in a cell, but the loop insert line without changing the range in the function.

don't find the syntax in python code to put function in cell and not text.

Does someone know the syntax to use in python code to put the sum function in the report, or the way in ods file to change the range of sum function when inserting line ?

Comment: You need to post some code with your question so we can try to help you.